# PyGame Collision with Tile Rendered map?

Tags: python, render, pygame, overwrite, tile

I'm having problems with my tile renderer, which goes through a text file and finds characters, converting them into rects. My problem is that only the most recent tile / rect is counted for collisions.

A video of my problem: http://youtu.be/7wAHp-vgrLU

My code works like this:

```
wall = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (40,40,40), (current_tile_x,current_tile_y,tile_size,tile_size), 0)
if wall.colliderect(collision) == 1:
print "Collision!"
```

The player's rect is defined as collision. The problem I think is that for every wall tile, the var wall gets overwritten, so how would I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 2):

You just answered yourself, you should make a iterable with all rects to be tested:

```
 #load all the rects in one list for example
 walls = get_wall_list() #returns a list [rect0,rect1,rectn]
 for wall in walls:
   if wall.colliderect(collision): #'if True == 1:' works as the same 'if True:'
     print "Collision!"
```